# EC2: Where did the disk space monitoring panel disappear to?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring, amazon-web-services

There used to be 8-10 different panels in the monitoring tab for instances in the EC2 web console (I have detailed monitoring enabled, but I suspect it only affects the monitoring intervals, not dimensions).

Recently, I noticed that there are only 5 panels there and the available disk space isn't one of them.

Where did it go and how can I bring it back?

Comment: Windows or Linux? Who's AMI?

Answer (score 0):

On my instances, EC2 has never been able to monitor disk space. This would require a user-space agent reporting back details of the file system to the virtual host. EC2 should not be able to monitor disk space usage from outside the host without the aid of something running on your instances.

Perhaps you have killed off whatever daemon was reporting these values?

Comment: I don't recall ever launching or even knowing about such a daemon.

Comment: Are you using an Amazon supplied AMI?